# a Python script that sends a keystroke when specific text comes up in a game chatbox

Tags: python, chatbot, keystroke

I've attached a picture. Every 41-45 minutes, the text "The World is having An Auto AFK Check. Type Something In OOC. You Have 30 Seconds To Respond." appears. I'd like it to detect when it does and send a keystroke to the game.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see the picture, but you could take a look at [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/)

They have a screenshot function and you can control the mouse and keyboard to write a message

Comment: Thank You so much i got the point. I have to ask one thing more that how can apply this script on my windows for any game?

Comment: In the case for pyautogui, it is going to take a screenshot, so be sure to keep your game window opened in the same position always (or fullscreen)

Comment: If you wish, you could create a virtual screen, so you could use your screen for something else rather then watch the game being played.

Comment: Sorry! As I wrote that text appears after 41 to 45 mins. so how python can detect this text as it appears and send stroke key by it self? I found pyautogui very useful but didn't found only this requirement.. which I m writing.